# Process builder Create Product and Pricebook Entry at the same time

Tags: process-builder, product, pricebookentry

We are trying to automate our product creation process, I have created a new object called internal request which has all the product fields we require and once an approval process is approved it sets off a process builder to create a product, The problem i am having is creating the pricebook entry straight after the product as i can't find a way to get the product link.

[image: Create Product]

This part is fine, its when i need to create the PBE, which i already have the list price and price book from the previous internal request object

[image: Create PBE]

any ideas would be hugely appreciated thanks!

Comment: I think you may not be able to do with just Process Builder but might need to have an autolaunched Flow called by the PB as that will be able to pick up the Id of the product to insert into the pricebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this purely in Process Builder. Instead, you'll need to use either an auto-launched flow, an [Apex invocation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm), or consider just writing a [trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) directly. Keep in mind that using a flow might run into governor limits if you decide you need to do batch updates in the future, so keep this mind.

Comment: Went with the trigger method as it allowed me more freedom with a few other fields